# QuickBlox sample code (android) failed to run

Tags: android, android-studio, quickblox

I tried to run the QuickBlox sample code in android studio from this
   http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample
It gets many errors. 
One of them :

```
Error:Failed to crunch file E:\android\quickblox-android-sdk-master (1)\quickblox-android-sdk-master\sample-custom-objects\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.0.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png into E:\android\quickblox-android-sdk-master (1)\quickblox-android-sdk-master\sample-custom-objects\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
Error:Execution failed for task ':sample-custom-objects:mergeDevDebugResources'.
Error:Failed to crunch file E:\android\quickblox-android-sdk-master (1)\quickblox-android-sdk-master\sample-custom-objects\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.0.1\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png into E:\android\quickblox-android-sdk-master (1)\quickblox-android-sdk-master\sample-custom-objects\build\intermediates\res\merged\dev\debug\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
```

I tried to delete the build file and  searched a lot but no luck. Any suggestion to solve this error will be appreciated.

Comment: asked more than few times ... more likely path's length problem (or spaces in path)

Comment: @Selvin how to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: I would try to change name of `quickblox-android-sdk-master (1)` folder to something shorter and without spaces

Comment: @Selvin oh you save my 2 days..thanks a lot